# Inner join con Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

**Obtengo el siguiente error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tea_funcion_fechasRestController':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'funcionFechaService';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tea_funcion_fechasServiceImpl':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'funcionFechaDao';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IFuncion_fechasDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.dao.IFuncion_fechasDao.findByObra(java.lang.String)!
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]     at
>   restTeatroproyecto.RestTeatroApplication.main(RestTeatroApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tea_funcion_fechasServiceImpl':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'funcionFechaDao';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IFuncion_fechasDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.dao.IFuncion_fechasDao.findByObra(java.lang.String)!
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     ... 24 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IFuncion_fechasDao': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.dao.IFuncion_fechasDao.findByObra(java.lang.String)!
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     ... 37 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.dao.IFuncion_fechasDao.findByObra(java.lang.String)!
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]     ... 47 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: funcion of:
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.entity.Tea_funcion_fechas [select fech from
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.entity.Tea_funcion_fechas fech INNER JOIN
>   fech.funcion f WHERE f.idObra = :idObra ]     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor707.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy548.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]  ... 60 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   funcion of: restTeatroproyecto.model.entity.Tea_funcion_fechas [select
>   fech from restTeatroproyecto.model.entity.Tea_funcion_fechas fech
>   INNER JOIN fech.funcion f WHERE f.idObra = :idObra ]  at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  ... 66
>   common frames omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could
>   not resolve property: funcion of:
>   restTeatroproyecto.model.entity.Tea_funcion_fechas    at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1805)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:505)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:376)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3912)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3698)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:572)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   ... 74 common frames
>   omitted

Mi entidad son las siguientes:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TEA_FUNCION")
public class Tea_funcion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String idfuncion;

    private String idempresa;
    private String idemisor;
    private String periodo;
    private String iddocumento;
    private String serie;
    private String numero;
    private Date fecha;
    private String idestado;
    private String ventana;
    private String idobra;
    private String idteatro;
    private Date desde;
    private Date hasta;
    private String glosa;
    private String idusuario;
    private Date fechacreacion;
    private String sincroniza;

    /* Sets & Gets */
    public void setIdempresa(String idempresa) {
        this.idempresa = idempresa;
    }

    public String getIdempresa() {
        return this.idempresa;
    }

    public void setIdfuncion(String idfuncion) {
        this.idfuncion = idfuncion;
    }

    public String getIdfuncion() {
        return this.idfuncion;
    }

    public void setIdemisor(String idemisor) {
        this.idemisor = idemisor;
    }

    public String getIdemisor() {
        return this.idemisor;
    }

    public void setPeriodo(String periodo) {
        this.periodo = periodo;
    }

    public String getPeriodo() {
        return this.periodo;
    }

    public void setIddocumento(String iddocumento) {
        this.iddocumento = iddocumento;
    }

    public String getIddocumento() {
        return this.iddocumento;
    }

    public void setSerie(String serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }

    public String getSerie() {
        return this.serie;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return this.numero;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public void setIdestado(String idestado) {
        this.idestado = idestado;
    }

    public String getIdestado() {
        return this.idestado;
    }

    public void setVentana(String ventana) {
        this.ventana = ventana;
    }

    public String getVentana() {
        return this.ventana;
    }

    public void setIdobra(String idobra) {
        this.idobra = idobra;
    }

    public String getIdobra() {
        return this.idobra;
    }

    public void setIdteatro(String idteatro) {
        this.idteatro = idteatro;
    }

    public String getIdteatro() {
        return this.idteatro;
    }

    public void setDesde(Date desde) {
        this.desde = desde;
    }

    public Date getDesde() {
        return this.desde;
    }

    public void setHasta(Date hasta) {
        this.hasta = hasta;
    }

    public Date getHasta() {
        return this.hasta;
    }

    public void setGlosa(String glosa) {
        this.glosa = glosa;
    }

    public String getGlosa() {
        return this.glosa;
    }

    public void setIdusuario(String idusuario) {
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
    }

    public String getIdusuario() {
        return this.idusuario;
    }

    public void setFechacreacion(Date fechacreacion) {
        this.fechacreacion = fechacreacion;
    }

    public Date getFechacreacion() {
        return this.fechacreacion;
    }

    public void setSincroniza(String sincroniza) {
        this.sincroniza = sincroniza;
    }

    public String getSincroniza() {
        return this.sincroniza;
    }
}
```

y

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

@Entity
@Table(name="TEA_CANALES_ATENCION")
public class Tea_funcion_fechas implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String item;

    private String idempresa;
    private Date fecha; 
    private String hora;


    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="idfuncion")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Tea_funcion tea_funcion;


    public void setIdempresa(String idempresa) {
        this.idempresa = idempresa;
    }

    public String getIdempresa() {
        return this.idempresa;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public String getHora() {
        return this.hora;
    }
```

Y este es mi dao de tea_funcion_fechas

```
public interface IFuncion_fechasDao extends CrudRepository<Tea_funcion_fechas, String>{

    @Query("select fech from Tea_funcion_fechas fech INNER JOIN fech.funcion f WHERE f.idObra = :idObra ")

    List<Tea_funcion_fechas> findByObra(String idObra);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido SO, te recomiendo que leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Puntualmente la parte de "¡Revisa la lectura antes de publicar!"

Comment: Parece un error tipográfico, estás escribiendo mal el nombre de los atributos: deberías usar `tea_funcion` en lugar de `funcion`

Answer (score 0):

El detalle esta en tu query, cuando haces el inner join en tu Entidad Tea_funcion_fechas  tienes **tea_funcion** y en el query  utilizas fech.funcion a lo cual deberia ser **fech.tea_funcion**.

```
@Query("select fech from Tea_funcion_fechas fech INNER JOIN fech.tea_funcionf WHERE f.idObra = :idObra ")
```

Te recomiendo que le des una leida a las convenciones de java.